# How to connect two arduinos with smartphone wirelessly

Tags: arduino-nano, nrf24l01+, hc-06

I'm working on a project that have two separate setups for Arduino, each Arduino read sensors and send data to smartphone. how to connect two Arduino then send all data to smartphone over Bluetooth?

Comment: Do you really want to use bluetooth, or is that just a idea? Should the two Arduinos connected with each other, or just each one with the phone? If the first, should this also be wireless?

Comment: Yes I want to use Bluetooth to connect Arduino with the smartphone, I want to use nrf24 module to connect two Arduino and send all data to the smartphone with HC-06 Bluetooth module, but I need a guide for connection and code.

Comment: Then please describe, what exactly your problem is. There are lots of tutorials about these on the web, so we need to know, how you can help you better, than they can.

Comment: The internet is full of information, mate. If you have a precise question we may help you with more acuracy